# Undefined index codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have a problem with result array in codeigniter

Model Is

```
 function ReadMessages($UID)
 {
    $query = $this->db->get('ls_messages3');
    return $query->result_array();
 }
```

Controller:

```
function messages()
{
  $data['user_info']['UnreadMessagesCount']=$this->pages_model->MessagesCount($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
  $this->load->model("articles_model");
  $this->load->model("login_model");
  $this->load->model("cabinet_model");
  $this->load->model("user_model");
  $this->load->library("form_validation");
  $data['pages'] = $this->pages_model->get_pages();
  $data['pages_info'] = $this->login_model->get_info("pm");
  $data['categories'] = $this->pages_model->get_cat();
  $data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('user');
  $data['user_info']['user_id']=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
  $data['user_info']['user_category']=$this->session->userdata('user_cat');
  $data['user_info']['avatar'] = $this->session->userdata('avatar');
  $data['error']='';
  $name="pm";
  $data['single_user'] = $this->login_model->user_info($data['user']);
  $data['mess'] = $this->user_model->ReadMessages($data['user_info']['user_id']);
  $this->template->page($data,$name);

}
```

And view:

```
<div id="body-in">
             <div id="profile_content">
                <?=var_dump($mess);?>
                <?=$mess['id'];?>

             </div>         
           </div>
```

Result array locate in $data['mess'] variable. When in view i use var_dump function to this variable, i get normal answer, like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["lstext"]=> string(95) " Hello! This is the Message! " ["isread"]=> string(5) "FALSE" ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-05-18" ["touser_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["time"]=> string(5) "16:06" } }
```

but when i'am trying to get a single value from this array i have error "Message: Undefined index" on this page

Comment: try this `<?=$mess[0]['id'];?>`

Comment: as kumar_v said you need to access the array within the array. If you don't need it to have multiple entries you could change your model to return `return $query->row_array();` that way the code you have done will work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Model code to

```
 function ReadMessages()
 {
    $query = $this->db->get('ls_messages3');
    return $query->row_array();
 }
```

and in controller

```
$this->user_model->ReadMessages($data['user_info']['user_id']);
```

to

```
$this->user_model->ReadMessages();
```

or

use `<?php echo $mess[0]['id']; ?>` in view